# Euler camera, rotation around x axis in camera local system

Tags: c++, math, game-engine, transformation

I have camera class that hold her orientation via euler angles and position. Something like that:

```
float m_x;
float m_y;
float m_z;

Vector4 m_pos;
```

And i want to move this camera free over the space.
When user move mouse up-down camera must rotate around x axis in her own coordinate system. But i want to hold only this three angles and position and nothing more.

So algorithm looks like this:

1. Find camera local system axis (u, v, n)
2. Rotate around u axis on angle alpha
3. Find angles around (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1) that answer to rotation on angle alpha around u axis
4. Add them to m_x, m_y, m_z

Question is: how can i calculate rotation angles in default coordinate system (i mean in (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0) and (0, 0, 1)) that answer to rotation angles in local camera coordinate system?

[image: Description]

Or may be better solution exists for this problem?

Comment: I'd highly suggest looking at quaternions, euler angles are rarely good for cameras, especially if you plan on rotating around all 3 axis.

Comment: thank you, i will, but anyway: how to calculate what i want? :)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actually want to do, is the camera `her` throughout the text? Besides that you're trying to do will net you a result which you most likely don't want, look up gimbal lock.

Comment: Yes. I can rephrase my question: how to calculate rotation in one coordinate system that answer to rotation in another coordinate system?

Comment: Answering the concise question from your comment, you can transform rotations between coordinate systems by applying a suitable transformation matrix. This in turn can be computed form the euler angles, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms).

Comment: @MvG please move your comment to answers, i will accept it because it really answers my question. Thank you. I don't guessed that i can just retrieve angles from rotation matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering the concise question from [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333667/euler-camera-rotation-around-x-axis-in-camera-local-system#comment19923471_14333667):

> how to calculate rotation in one coordinate system that answer to rotation in another coordinate system?

You can transform rotations between coordinate systems by applying a suitable transformation matrix. This in turn can be computed form the euler angles, see the [Wikipedia section on conversion formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_formalisms_in_three_dimensions#Conversion_formulae_between_formalisms).

Depending on your application, you might or might not have to take translations into account as well. As I understand your question, you can concentrate on the rotation part of each transformation.